# Python selenium get tag value of a selected element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using the code below to find all the elements with class value = "ng_isolate_scope". What I would need to do though is to capture the tag value of the selected elements, since I need this information for further analysis

```
<span class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="ng-isolate-scope">
```

Code:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-isolate-scope")
for elem in elems:
    tag_value = elem.get_tag()
    print("element found with tag value = " + str(tag_value))
```

However, tag_value() doesn't exist. What can I do to capture the tag value of an element?
Thanks

Comment: Are you have tried Xpath and CSS selector rather than class_name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

updated:
Its bit tricky, here my approach is to get outerHTML of element and then splitting the first word (which is tag name). So you can try:

```
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-isolate-scope")
    for element in elements:
      outerhtml = element.get_attribute('outerHTML ') // to extract outerHTML 
      tag_value=outerhtml.split('',1)[0] // to extract first word
      print("element found with tag value = " + tag_value)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this seems like Andrei's answer above. I'm aware of element.text but I don't need the text of an element, I would need the value of element's tag (usually div, span, a, input, button, ecctera...)

Comment: thanks, I immediately tried thinking this was exactly what I needed but for some weird reason it only gets the text of the element and not the html. I tried it on a bunch of elements but it doesn't seem to capture the html code. Does it work on your end?

Comment: so I changed the code from inner to outerHTML and it worked! Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake here. You are right it is outerHTML instead of innerHTML. I have updated my answer. Please accept this as an answer if it helped you in anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I right understand, you want a text of a tag:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-isolate-scope")
for elem in elems:
    tag_value = elem.text # get text of an element
    print("'element found with tag value = " + tag_value + "'")
```

for example:

```
<span class="ng-isolate-scope">span tag</span>
<div class="ng-isolate-scope">div tag</div>
```

will produce:

```
'element found with tag value = span tag'
'element found with tag value = div tag'
```

---

EDIT:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html.parser import HTMLParser

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789088/python-selenium-get-tag-value-of-a-selected-element/51789139#51789139")
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source) # get HTML

list = list() # create a list

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs): # get start tags
        list.append(tag) # store them in the list


parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(str(parsed_html.body.find('div', attrs={'id':'question-header'}))) # feed parser with parsed HTML

print(list[0]) # first element in the list is the tag you need
```

Output:

```
div
```

Reference to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

Comment: thank you Andrei. What I would need is the actual tag value "span" and "div". I don't think elem.text does the job. I give you another more concrete example. If you go to this sample page: https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice  and check the html code of the "Hide/Show Example" element, what I need to capture is the tag of that element, that in this case would be "input".

Comment: Many thanks Andrei. I was after a selenium solution but appreciated your support.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by get the tagName attribute directly, without need to parsing the outerHTML:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ng-isolate-scope")
for element in elements:
  tag_name = element.get_attribute('tagName')
  print(tag_name) ## INPUT / A / BUTTON
```